# Is it possible to repair damage to a radiators coating?

Tags: repair, radiator

One of our brand new radiators got damaged while having some other work done.

Is there anything that can be done to repair the patch where the coating has been taken off?

[image: Photo of damaged radiator]

Comment: Besides a dab of primer and paint, not much.  Looks like baked on enamel and would need professional repair to make look like new.  Might have the name of coating wrong but seems to be the same as on old style cast iron bathtubs.

Comment: Maybe a product for repairing dings in cast iron bath tubs?

Comment: If it was damaged by a contractor, they (or their insurance) should buy you a new one, as this will never be "just like new." If you damaged it, it will never be just like new either, but buying a new one is optional.

Comment: Have better things to do with money than spending it on very minor cosmetic damage.  Someones else money, okay.

Comment: can the radiator be reversed?

Comment: Radiator paint used to be available (in UK) from 'International'., and several coats, to build up the crater (place the rad. so that crater is at the highest point).

Comment: In the US, small jars of touch up "paint" in various shades are widely available for similar-sized chips in enamel sinks. As @Tim notes, just build up the depth with multiple coats. Also, as of mid-2010s there were still "used radiator and bathtub" stores in some US cities like Cambridge, MA, that refurbished radiators and knew how to properly fix damage like this.